# Looping through file in Python

Tags: python, api, loops, parsing, twitter

I am fairly new to using Python and the Twitter API as well. I have a text file that is formatted as each line having one or more Twitter handles on it (example: 
nameOne nameTwo nameThree
)

For sake of clarity, let's say that we are talking specifically about this line.
The goal is to create a program that loops through each line and prints out the followers and tweets of the first name (nameOne) as well as the relationship between the first name and each of the subsequent names (relationship between nameOne and nameTwo as well as nameOne and nameThree, but not necessary between nameTwo and nameThree).

This is the code that I have thus far (after using the authentication keys necessary to access the Twitter API at the top of the code):

```
handles = open('inputResearch.rtf', 'r')

entries = handles.readlines()

#start to read through the files and print out the friend information
for entry in entries:
    friends = entry.rsplit(' ', 1)
    firstName = friends[0]
    temp = friends[1:len(friends)-1]
    print(firstName, " followers are:\n")
    for follower in twitterRest.followers_ids(firstName):
        print (twitterRest.get_user(follower).screen_name)
        print("\n")
    print(firstName, " tweets are:\n")
    for status in twitterRest.user_timeline(firstName):
        print (status.text)
        print("\n")
    if(temp != ""):
        for item in friends:
            x =twitterRest.show_friendship(source_screen_name=firstName, 
            target_screen_name=temp)
            print(firstName, " frienship with ", temp, ":\n", x, "\n")
```

And this is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-e07ede25e593>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/ekvdg/Desktop/BYU/Research/Python Files/input:output.py', wdir='/Users/ekvdg/Desktop/BYU/Research/Python Files')
  File "/Users/ekvdg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/ekvdg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/Users/ekvdg/Desktop/BYU/Research/Python Files/input:output.py", line 35, in <module>
    for follower in twitterRest.followers_ids(firstName):
  File "/Users/ekvdg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Users/ekvdg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]
```

I have determined that it is breaking right after printing out "followers are" and I don't know if it is a problem with my use of the Twitter API or with using Python. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: please, include the full error traceback in the question, not just the error, but the full traceback. It helps us determine the error and the best solution

Answer (score 0):

And you're sure the page is there when accessed in a different fashion, say, manually?
I don't know the API but it's not obvious from what you've written that the page does indeed exist. It just looks like a simple 404 and according to twitter's API reference that's precisely what "code 34" means.

In any case, you're likely to encounter non-existent accounts sooner or later. Perhaps you should consider putting your gets inside `try-except` statements, like so:

```
try:
    followers_ids = twitterRest.followers_ids(firstName)
except TweepError:
    # log it, try the next guy or do something else entirely
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. Like I said, I am really new to the Twitter API (or just any API in general) so I wasn't even sure how to check if it existed. I've been going off of the API reference page, but from what I can tell, it hasn't been updated in a while, so I'm still trying to figure out what works and what doesn't.